# how to sum from array of object using lodash only?

Tags: lodash

hey I want to calculate the sum of one property from array of object using lodash

suppose the array of object looks like this ...

```
salary":[{
   "bills":[{"electricity":300,"milk":500},
            {"electricity":240,"milk":200},
            {"electricity":800,"milk":900}]    
}]
```

I want to calculate the sum of 'milk' from that object using lodash.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use nested [`_.sumBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sumBy) calls. The internal gets the sum of `milk` from one `salary`, and the external sums all salaries:

```js
const data = {"salary":[{"bills":[{"electricity":300,"milk":500},{"electricity":240,"milk":200},{"electricity":800,"milk":900}]}]}

const result = _.sumBy(data.salary, ({ bills }) => _.sumBy(bills, 'milk'))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
const bills = salary.map((s)=> s.bills)

_(bills).map((objs,key)=>({
    'milk': _.sumBy(objs, 'milk')
})).value
```